# What is the best solution to separate uv's?

Tags: uv, edit-mode, workflow

I made a light saber but I made only two parts, 1 hilt and 1 blade.
The blade is good together since it has around 300 edges, but since I want to add a lot of detail on the hilt, I want it to be separated to somewhere around 4-5 different parts so the uv's itself can be separate.

Or should I just leave it together and work on it like that?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "separate UV's"? That you want to separate the part in a different object? What's exactly the problem that need a solution? What are your concerns?

Comment: You don't need to separate objects to use higher resolution images-- you just need to use higher resolution images.  It's not the object count that matters: there is more resolution in a single 2k image than there is in 3 1k images.  What makes good UV depends, in part, on how you want to make the texture images, but remember that you can always use multiple UV, and you can always bake from multiple UV to singleton UV.